# wcf instance variable getting changed by a separate instance

Tags: .net, wcf, concurrency

I have a wcf which is configured as:

```
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession
```

I've a variable defined globally which I expect to hold its value throughout the session and it is holding that value.

I've one instance which initializes this variable and holds its value (say 123)
I've another instance which initializes this variable and holds its value (say 456)

However, after the second instance initializes the variable, the value for the first instance (session) becomes 456!! which wasn't expected!!

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: How is the variable defined? Is it static?

Comment: Can you show us the code in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine - recheck your code as below.

Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{       
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData();      
}
```

Service implementation

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    int i = 0;

    public string GetData()
    {
        i++;
        return string.Format("Instance number: {0}", i);
    }       
}
```

Now calling the service with same instance will give incremented value of **"int i"** from GetData but for new instance it will start with 1.

See below calls from client

```
using (var client = new HttpProxy.Service1Client("NetTcpBinding_IService1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Response {0}", client.GetData());
    Console.WriteLine("Response {0}", client.GetData());
}

using (var client2 = new HttpProxy.Service1Client("NetTcpBinding_IService1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Response {0}", client2.GetData());
    Console.WriteLine("Response {0}", client2.GetData());
}

using (var client = new HttpProxy.Service1Client("WSHttpBinding_IService1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Response {0}", client.GetData());
    Console.WriteLine("Response {0}", client.GetData());
}
```

Creating proxy instance with CreateChannel

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
                    var address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1");
                    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WcfServLib.IService1>(binding, address);

                    WcfServLib.IService1 proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

                    Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData());
                    Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData());


                    channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WcfServLib.IService1>(binding, address);
                    proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

                    Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData());
                    Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData());

                    channelFactory.Close();
```

Service implementation

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode= InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)] public class Service1 : IService1 { int i = 0; public string GetData()
    {
        return string.Format("SessionID:{0}, Local variable i:{1}", OperationContext.Current.SessionId, i++);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I am using following code to create instance


Dim myBinding As NetTcpBinding 
myBinding = New NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, False) 
Dim oChannelFactory As New ChannelFactory(Of MasterWCF.ICaseflowWCFService)(myBinding)
myBinding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(10, 10, 10, 10)
myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647 
oChannelFactory.Endpoint.Address = New EndpointAddress(NetTcpAddress) 
Dim proxy As MasterWCF.IWCFService 
proxy = oChannelFactory.CreateChannel()

Comment: see my updated answer I have given example of Creating proxy instance with CreateChannel.